# Preciso importar um módulo várias vezes?

Tags: python, módulo-python

Eu tenho um arquivo de classes e um arquivo para o programa principal, nos dois arquivos eu preciso do Pygame. Eu faço a importação das classes no programa principal dessa forma `from classes import *`. Preciso importar o Pygame nas classes e no programa principal ou dessa forma o Pygame que foi importado nas classes é importado também pro programa principal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você tem no seu arquivo  "classes.py" algo como:

```
import pygame

class Classe1(...):
    ...
```

e depois no arquivo principal:

```
from classes import *
```

Tanto as classes definidas, como o "pygame" que foi importado no arquivo classes.py são importados para o arquivo principal. 
O comando `import` traz variáveis definidas nos módulos - não importa se as variáveis sejam criadas diretamente com o sinal de "=", ou sejam referências à funções, e portanto criadas com a palavra chave "def", classes, criadas com a palavra chave "class" ou sejam importadas de outro módulo de "além", com o comando "import". Uma variável que exista no módulo "class1" pode ser importada de outro módulo, e a variável "pygame" que faz referência ao pacote pygame não é exceção.

O que acontece é que não é considerada uma boa prática usar o `from XXX import *`. Inclusive isso quebra o funcionamento de várias ferramentas de análise de código e varias funcionalidades das IDEs.

Você deveria importar nome por nome do que vai usar, que estiver definido no seu arquivo "classes1", e não usar o "*". O uso do "*" só deve ser feito mesmo nas exceções que confirmam a regra de que ele não deve ser usado.  :-)

Dito isso, é possível escrever no seu módulo principal:

```
from classes1 import class1, class2, class3, pygame
```

Mas não é recomendado - o melhor mesmo é você importar o Pygame como pygame no módulo principal, e as classes que deseja do seu módulo, sem usar o "*":

```
import pygame
from classes1 import class1, class2, class3
```

O que é importante ter em mente aí, é que o Python não vai "importar duas vezes" o módulo pygame. Em tempo de execução, ele simplesmente vai ver que o pygame já foi importado em outro módulo, e criar uma variável no módulo atual pra apontar para o mesmo módulo pygame importado no módulo "classes1". Os arquivos do pygame não são lidos mais de uma vez do disco, nenhum arquivo é compilado mais de uma vez, e nenhuma funcionalidade do pygame vai estar presente de forma duplicada na memória.

Então, resumindo - sim - o correto em Python é importar em cada módulo tudo o que o código daquele módulo for usar, sem depender disso estar disponível em outro módulo que você também vai importar. Só que não há nenhum impacto de performance com isso, apenas clareza que facilita a manutenção futura do seu código.

O Pygame em particular tem uma situação que foi feita pra se usar o `import *` - as constantes com os códigos de teclas e de eventos do mouse e *joystick*. Elas estão disponíveis separadamente no módulo `pygame.locals`.

Então você pode fazer, no seu módulo de classes:

```
from pygame.locals import *
```

E ter disponíveis para usar os códigos tais como `K_ESCAPE` , e etc... e ao importar só as classes por nome no módulo principal, não polui o seu *namespace* com as centenas de nomes do `pygame.locals`.

Answer (score 3):

A importação normalmente vale apenas para o arquivo onde ela é feita, então precisa importar explicitamente em todos que forem usar aquele módulo.

Claro que se você importa um módulo em um arquivo e depois importa **tudo** o que está nele em outra parte da aplicação, a principal como chama na pergunta, o que foi importado lá fica disponível para uso. Mas note que isto só funciona se importar todos os símbolos por completo. Então, sim, se fizer `from classes import *` não precisa importar novamente. Só não deve fazer isto.

O problema é que se faz desta forma polui os nomes que estão sendo usados e começa jogar contra justamente para o que o módulo serve que é segregar partes da aplicação e as bibliotecas.

A importação é só um mecanismo para disponibilizar símbolos de outros códigos para o código atual. Você diz quais deseja.

Embora tecnicamente possível aproveitar importação, não deve fazer isto.

O `import *` pode até ajudar digitar menos, mas causa dificuldades na organização do projeto.